# Populate user control TextBox with Session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

How do I populate this field from a session variable? Everything I have tried has left me with it not being populated. The session variable has data.  I would prefer to set it in the .ascx but can go in the .ascx.cs codebehind if need be. I would rather not populate it from the main .aspx file. Assume: Session["var1"] = "has data";

Code in some.ascx:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="mybox" Text="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
mybox.Text = (String)Session["var1"];
```

Comment: It still appears blank using this code in the Page_Load of .ascx.cs and also with the line: mybox.Text = "some data"; Is something else amiss?   in some.ascx I have <%@ Control Language="C#" CodeFile="some.ascx.cs" Inherits="myclass" %>

Comment: Found the problem. Something was amiss. The code was inside a condition that wasn't hitting.